# Uncaught ReferenceError: función is not defined

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema, no entiendo por qué no muestra los datos, al ser ingresados.

```
<label for="nombre"> Nombre: </label>
<input type="text" id="nombre" />
<input type="button" onclick="guardarDatos()" value="Guardar datos" />
<p id="datos"> </p>
<input type="button" onclick="recuperarDatos()" value="Recuperar datos" />
```

JS

```
function guardarDatos(){
 localStorage.nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
}

function recuperarDatos(){
 if ((localStorage.nombre != undefined)) {
  document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML = "Nombre: " + localStorage.nombre;
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML = "No has introducido tu nombre";
 }
}
```

Mi idea es guardar el nombre y luego usar la variable nombre, en varias parte del html con un ID.

Olvidé mencionar que tengo los siguientes errores.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: guardarDatos is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):67)
onclick @ (index):67

(index):69 Uncaught ReferenceError: recuperarDatos is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):69)
```

Pueden ver mi codigo,

https://jsfiddle.net/JDLA1/zfgjr41s/

Comment: Estás usando algun tipo de snippet online como `jsfiddle`?

Comment: Si, he actualizado la pregunta @lois6b

Comment: Te he actualizado el fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/zfgjr41s/1/). El problema es en JS que carga las funciones en el onLoad, pon en Head

Comment: Gracias @lois6b, la proxima formula la respuesta para darte puntuacion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dejando a un lado el uso de `LocalStorage`(explicado por Trauma en su respuesta), el problema es que el `jsfiddle` carga las funciones JS en `onLoad` por defecto.

Si quieres cambiar el ajuste, pulsando en el boton  `Javascript ⚙`, ahi puedes elegir cuándo se cargan.

Si lo cambias a `no wrap - in head` (que es donde se añaden los `<script>'s`), funciona bien:

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/zfgjr41s/1/

Comment: Muchas Gracias, por el dato!... como puedo despues de darle guardar datos, ocultar el formulario y dejar solo el nombre?

Comment: @JuanDavid no se exactamente lo que quieres. algo [asi](https://jsfiddle.net/zfgjr41s/5/) ? (es algo muy cutre y basico)

Comment: jajaja, Eso esta perfecto, Gracias!

Comment: @JuanDavid de nada, me alegra ser de ayuda

Answer (score 3):

La [API LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) **no** se usa así.

En lugar de como lo estás haciendo, deberías de hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
function guardarDatos(){
  localStorage.setItem( "nombre", document.getElementById("nombre").value );
}

function recuperarDatos(){
  if( localStorage.getItem( "nombre" ) != undefined ) {
    document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML = "Nombre: " + localStorage.getItem( "nombre" );
  } else {
    document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML = "No has introducido tu nombre";
  }
}
```

Comment: Actualizado, Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

El código que tienes funciona perfectamente, pruebalo en un fichero html y js en vez de jsfiddle, si bien la mejor manera de usar LocalStorage es como bien dice el compañero @Trauma. Saludos